# Android : Offline authentication in android without sms

Tags: android, authentication, offlineapps

I am developing an Android application for my college magazine. This application will be totally offline but should be accessed by college students only by using their student ID.

Is their any solution to authenticate by using student ID only and that too offline?

Comment: if your id has qr code

Comment: @Divyesh can you elaborate your answer,Please

Comment: You can store all student ID on the app and then check vs them, but this is not really secured, as rooted phone can access the ID`s

Comment: Do you want to create a magazine ... offline? No server side?

Comment: At some point, the app needs to be online, to download magazine content. Only allow the app to download content for authorized users, where you check authorization as part of the download process. Do not worry about authentication/authorization otherwise (for already-downloaded content).

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can use sharedpreferences,preferencehelper and local sqlite database as per your project requirement.

but you are providing magazines in offline?
if yes then use above said methods or if you are using internet for downloading magazines then its better to authenticate online.

Comment: Actually this magazine is updated once a year so there is no need of internet.